# how can i make a countdown timer that goes past the 60minutes

Tags: php

This is the flow of commands on my login page

- User loads page
- php checks if the ip address is in the db, if not it adds it
- php checks in the ip address is blocked in the db, if not it proceeds

if it is blocked the script will proceed to get the time the ip was blocked at from the db and calculate the amount of time left until the user can try to login again. The blockout time is 15minutes.

However the problem is that if the user was blocked at 45-59 minutes past the hour then 45+15= 00(as 60 doesn't come up on the time) and any number between 45 and 60 excluding 45 and 60 will go past the hour so for example if i get blocked out at 11:48 i will be unblocked at 12:03.

The problem, if you haven't already figured out is how do i code the countdown timer so it goes past the hour and doesn't spazz out when it goes past 59minutes.

Also i want to do this in php as i have no need to actually present the time left in real-time.

Comment: Time keeping in code is typically done with UNIX timestamps, which do not exhibit this problem. How *are* you keeping time instead? You kinda need to bend over backwards to actually run into this problem...

Comment: @deceze seems like a very distant cousin of Y2K

Comment: @deceze: Beware Y2K38. It's already bitten me a few times, for things like  "this contract is valid for 30 years." UNIX timestamp should be deprecated, consider http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: @Piskvor Doesn't really sound like Y2K38 in this case, but it's certainly something to be aware of when using *32 bit* UNIX timestamps.

Comment: @deceze: That's not an issue in the question, indeed - I was reacting to "typically done with timestamps"; that's a bit of a cowboy-coding artifact of PHP, I think: convenient, but error-prone. Also, UNIX timestamp is *defined* as 32-bit, so unless it's redefined *eeeeverywhere* (improbable), I'd rather not recommend using it.

Comment: @Piskvor Where is it "defined as 32-bit"?! The concept of a UNIX timestamp doesn't include any particular implementation, and most implementations are being updated to 64bit integers so as to avoid Y2K38.

Comment: Essentially, in all code (within the margin of statistical error) that's running today. I posit that a *majority* of that code will go unfixed before hitting a significant number of Y2K38 bugs. Yes, *new* code written *might* have 64-bit integers, if it's recompiled or the underlying stack is: PHP still has PHP_INT_MAX = 2147483647; and MySQL UNIX timestamps are defined as 32 bit.

In other words, using UNIX timestamp in high-level code was always a kludge; better to move on to saner implementations now, while the pressure to do so is relatively low.

Comment: @Piskvor If you set up PHP on any modern \*NIX system with its package manager, you're almost certain to get a 64bit version of PHP where `PHP_INT_MAX != 2147483647`. It's perfectly possible to rely on 64bit these days in PHP (if you have even a modicum of control over your environment). Sure, you certainly *should* use the higher abstraction afforded by `DateTime`, but UNIX timestamps are still alive and useful.

Comment: Fair point. I'd go for "undead", even though I agree with "useful" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current minute is never an issue. You are concerned with the *duration* since last blocked, not with "what time was that":

block_user.php:

```
<?php
$now = new DateTime();
write_block_into_database($ip_address, $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
?>
```

check_block.php

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT 1 FROM sometable WHERE ip_address=? AND DATE_ADD(blocked_at, INTERVAL 1 HOURS) >= NOW()';
if(get_result($sql, $ip_address)) { 
   // this address is blocked
} else {
   // no recent block found
}
```

Or, if you want to do the comparison in PHP:

check_locally.php:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT blocked_at FROM sometable WHERE ip_address=?";
$db_row = get_row($sql,$ip_address);
if ($db_row) {
    $blocked = new DateTime($db_row->blocked_at);
    $blocked->modify('+1 hour');
    $now = new DateTime();

    if ($blocked >= $now) {
       // still blocked
    } else {
       // was blocked earlier, no more
    }
} else {
    // not blocked
}
```

In other words: "if I take the time the IP was blocked and add one hour, is now still before that point in time?"

Example:

- blocked at 12:48
- checking at 13:10: 12:48 + 1 hour = 13:48, 13:48 >= 13:10, fail
- checking at 15:10: 12:48 + 1 hour = 13:48, 13:48 < 15:10, pass

Comment: The functions are obviously pseudocode for writing/reading to/from database - it's not entirely relevant how that's implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I managed to come up with

```
$date = new DateTime();
$currentTime = $date->getTimestamp();

$blockTime = "1453494620";//This value will be taken from the mysql db
$timeElapsed = $currentTime - $blockTime;

echo "Current Time: $currentTime";
echo "<br>Block Time: $blockTime <br>";

if ($timeElapsed < 900){
    $leftTime = ((900 - $timeElapsed) / 60) + 1;
    $DotPosition = (stripos($leftTime, ".")) + 1;

    if($DotPosition == 3 || $DotPosition == 2){
        $leftTime = substr($leftTime, 0, $DotPosition - 1);
    }

    if($leftTime == 1){
        $minutesString = "minute";
    } else $minutesString = "minutes";

    echo "<br>You are blocked from trying to login for too many incorrect tries.
          <br>Please try again in $leftTime $minutesString.";
} else {
    /*for test purpose, here the user will get unblocked on the mysql by updating the
    ips blockout field */
    echo "<br>You have been unblocked.";
}
```

> Current Time: 1453495488
>
> Block Time: 1453494620
>
> You are blocked from trying to login for too many incorrect tries.
>
> Please try again in 1 minute.

Thank you guys for telling me about UNIX Timestamps. If I knew about them I wouldn't have asked. :)